# How to create Form with background color in j2me

Tags: java, forms, java-me

How do I create a simple custom Form using canvas, with background color?

```
myform=new Form("myform");
myform.append(cmd);
myform.setCommandListner(this);
display.setCurrent(myform);
```

Here I want to set the form's background color

Comment: can you say what you have tried so far, and include some code? It would be helpful to see links to other questions here that have not helped

Comment: Form myform=new Form("myform");
myform.append(cmd);
myform.setCommandListner(this);
display.setCurrent(myform);

here i want form background color

Comment: check the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863901/jme-how-to-get-the-complete-screen-in-white-without-buttons-etc-etc

Comment: @Jeff Bowman marked this question as duplicated to an existing question, but I don't think they are same. In that old question, a Canvas was brought to front with custom background color, here the question is how to set the background color of Form, they are different questions.

Comment: Unlike javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas, there's no method in javax.microedition.lcdui.Form you can use to change the background color of Form. The look and feel of Form depends on the implementation of phone vendor (or OS), developer don't have much control of it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/

Comment: @durron597 this is not a duplicate question.